# Mapbox.js: Bind dynamic popups with featureLayer?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I am building a [multiple chloropleth map](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/choropleth-joined-data-multiple-variables/) using v2.2.1 of Mapbox.js with [`featureLayer`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.2.1/l-mapbox-featurelayer/). Now  I would like to add tooltips with custom content on hover event.

This code is working well to set up the featurelayer and add styles to each layer:

```
_this.orgLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer(null, {
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                    radius: 8,
                    color: "#000",
                    weight: 1,
                    opacity: 1,
                    fillOpacity: 0.97
                });
            }
        })
        .loadURL(boundsUrl)
        .addTo(map)
        .on('ready', joinDataAndSetupMap);
...
// once data joined and map set up, add styles to each layer.
// this gets called at initialization and again when the map is updated. 
_this.orgLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) {
        var val = layer.feature.properties.data[month];
        var style = _this.getStyle(val);
        layer.setStyle(style);
    });
```

But I'm not sure how to bind popups on hover. Could anyone suggest the best way to do this?

[The documentation mentions a `popupOptions` option](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.2.1/l-mapbox-featurelayer/), but I can't see how to use those to specify dynamic content, or bind the popups to mouseover not click.

Maybe I need to do something inside the `eachLayer` loop? If so, what?

UPDATE: I've got this, it works but I don't think it's the most efficient way, because it has to re-add the events each time the layer is regenerated. It would be better to add them once at the beginning, wouldn't it:

```
    _this.orgLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) {
        var style = _this.getStyle(monthData[ratio],
                                   quintiles,
                                   layer.feature.properties.name,
                                   _this.activeNames);
        layer.setStyle(style);
        var closeTooltip;
        layer.on('mousemove', function(e) {
            var layer = e.target;
            var html = utils.constructTooltip(_this.options,
                layer.feature.properties.name,
                monthData.date,
                monthData[y],
                monthData[x],
                monthData[ratio]);
            this.popup.setLatLng(e.latlng);
            this.popup.setContent(html);
            if (!this._map) this.popup.openOn(this.map);
            window.clearTimeout(closeTooltip);
            if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera) {
                layer.bringToFront();
            }
        }, _this);
        layer.on('mouseout', function(e) {
            var _this = this;
            closeTooltip = window.setTimeout(function() {
               _this.map.closePopup();
            }, 100);
        }, _this);
        layer.on('click', function(e) {
            this.map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
        }, _this);
    });
```

Also, it's quite jerky on mouseover. Is there a way to debounce the events?